# HTML URL with data variables

Tags: html, vb.net

I'm quite familiar with php and when submitting variables with data values on a URL from a form in php using the 'GET' function I would call it like

```
http://localhost/sms/incoming.php?sender=$originator&receiver=$recipient&msgdata=$messagedata&recvtime=$receivedtime&msgid=$messageid
```

where the variables being sent by the get function are

```
sender=$originator&receiver=$recipient&msgdata=$messagedata&recvtime=$receivedtime&msgid=$messageid
```

However I don't know how to submit them on a plain HTML URL that doesn't use any scripting language. I would like to submit the values to a plain HTML page so that my server listens to the request and gets to read the data values contained on the URL. My server is on VB.NET but does not support any scripting language.

I just want it to be listening to any HTTP request then reading the data contained in the 'GET' function that sent the data in the request. Please help me know how to submit data on a plain HTML URL or how to read data from a URL in VB.Net because any of them can work on my application . Thanks.

Comment: I guess this question needs clarification. Add information about the type of the software (server, languages) and the intended use case. Show us some scenario - who issues a request? What responses are expected for given requests? Simplify it a little - don't include all the variables - just pick one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to admit that I do not fully understand your question.

You say that your server does not support any scripting language. Do you mean that your server does not support any *programming* language? VB.NET *is* a language, so I am a little confused.

> [H]ow to submit data on a plain HTML URL, or how to read data from a URL in VB.Net?

The first part of your question is not clear, because *submitting* the values is very easy: just type the URL with values in the address bar of your browser, or put them (in the same form) as an address, for any program which is able to make a HTTP request (wget, for example).

Instead of typing the values directly in the link, you may use a `<form>` element in HTML. Just define that the method should be GET, instead of default POST:

```
<form action="sms/incoming.html" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="sender">
  ...and so on.
```

An important question is: **What language you have available on the 'requesting' part?** Do you send requests manually? From PHP? Are the requests sent by users, from a HTML page?

For the second part of your question, you already received an [answer by Robert Beaubien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890035/how-can-my-server-program-read-the-variables-sent-using-a-http-get-request-meth/6890800#6890800): *You can get them from the Context.Request.QueryString object*

You have responded that it does not work for you. So, the question is: **What type of server is listening to your requests? What language have you available?**

In that other question you have included some code, which suggests that you can program your server in VB.NET.

Is that code related to your problem asked here?

If yes, then can you debug what is the variable `sbuffer` if your issue a request with parameters? *(Type this in your browser's address bar.)*
If your `sbuffer` contains the same string as you have typed in the browser, then just parse the string after a question mark (`?`), split it by ampersands (`&`) and by equal signs (`=`), and you have all your parameters.

Comment: Thanks man. My server is communicating with another server that is sending its request in HTML standard 'POST' functions so I just wanted to know a way that my server can listen to the requests and respond. In the process of listening, my server is supposed to get data values from the requesting URL because it contains the data values required.

Comment: Ok, the listening server is written in what language? VB.NET? Does it listen directly on the port, or is it behind some other server software? Basically, your server should receive just some string: "GET /fubar?msgid=99", so you can do anything with this. Does your server receive similar text data?

Comment: I dont know what language the other server is written in but it sends 'POST' requests in POST content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded. which submits data in a common form so assuming my server is a scripting language like php i wanted to know how to read values submitted in a standard HTML form. The server recieves a request like GET/api?sender=$originator&receiver=$recipient&msgdata=$messagedata&recvtime=$receivedtime&msgid=$messageid

Answer (score 1):

You might look up 'POST' instead of using 'GET'.

For instance, your html might look like:

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">

<input type="text" name="name_of_input_field" />

</form>
```

And then your PHP would have:

```
$formVariable = $_POST['name_of_input_field'];
```

Comment: My server does not support any scripting language

Answer (score 0):

Try using Javascript to parse the query string. Off the top of my head, I'd think something like this would work (or something close to it):

```
qs = window.location.search.substring(1);
qs_vals = qs.split("&");
```

That should get you an array (qs_vals) of var=val for each element in the array. Then you could just loop through them to stuff the values into a dense array, or put the values into new variables names, or whatever you'd like to do with it.

Comment: My server does not support any scripting language

Comment: Javascript runs client side, so your server doesn't need to support it. This is the only way I know of, that you can make a static HTML file accept variables.